# Unable to load the database configuration in Cakephp shell

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

Cake console throw error **Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.**

I have created the shell with name `report` in report shell I'm fetching record from model `User`

**ReportShell.php**

```
class ReportShell extends AppShell {

    public $uses = array('User');

    public function main() {
        $opt =$this->User->find();
        $this->out(opt);
    }

}
```

[image]

when I run this command `cake report -app /opt/lampp/htdocs/corpveda/app` I get following error

[image]

Note: I'm using xampp server for running the php application in Ubuntu.

Comment: So, what exactly is unclear about the error message? If you read it just do what it demands.

Comment: To be fair, the message could be more precise... it's unfortunate that the more specific messages from PDO exceptions, and the ones defined in the CakePHP source like "_Selected driver is not enabled_" get swallowed on the CLI.

Comment: I don't understand why the data configuration are loading from the `usr/share/php` path although my application is at the `/opt/lampp/htdocs/corpveda`

Comment: application is running in browser but if failed when I run through CLI